# Including a specific Javascript Script in a template. Is my code correct?

Tags: functions, javascript

I have a contact form that I would to place within my WordPress theme that pulls in specific Javascript AND CSS Files.

To pull in the Javascript (called x.js) is this correct? I tested it and it seems to work fine, I just want to see whether I've done this correctly!

Also - would I do exactly the same for a .css file?

Here's the php code I placed in the functions file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','contactform');
function contactform(){
if ( is_page_template('page-contact.php') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('contact-javascript', 'js/x.js');
   }
}
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to give the part to the js/x.js file, the rest is correct.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what you mean by 'give the part' - do you mean that the Javascript Code must be in the 'x.js' file?

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

like this get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js',

Comment: thank you. Yes, I need to learn why that is applied...

Comment: get_template_directory_uri()  gets the path to the file

Comment: Would it be exactly the same for .css? I mean to load a specific .css file for this template?

Comment: yes, it works the same for CSS